# JQuery Add live() listener to form handler

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the following code which is on my index.html page. Whenever I submit a form on this page, the alert is picked up and appears on screen followed by the output the form-handling script being dumped in the #results div. Perfect!

```
$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function() {

        alert("Form submitted!");

        $('#results').html('Submitting...');
    },

    success: function(output) {
        var $out = $('#results');
        $out.html('Your results:');
        $out.append('<div>'+ output +'</div>');
    }
});
```

However, if I was to update a div on the page with a new form and then submit this newly available form, I am instead redirected to a blank page with the results of the form-handling script on screen.

### QUESTION:

Is there a way to avoid this page change and to submit the form while remaining on the current page?

I have been playing around with `.live()` and a few others but cant seem to make sense of it...

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

Just take `form` out of `#results` or update the form html `$('form').html('whatever');` and you'll keep your event binding.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would bind the `.ajaxForm()` after you create the new `<form/>` element.

```
function before(){
  alert("Form submitted!");
  $('#results').html('Submitting...');
};

function allGood(){
  var $out = $('#results');
  $out.html('Your results:');
  $out.append('<div>'+ output +'</div>');
}

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: before,
    success: allGood
});

//do something to create a new form
var $form = $("<form/>");

$form.ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: before,
    success: allGood
});

$("#someDiv").append($form);
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/n48eK/)**

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just use jquerys [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method and do the necesssary in success function there.

All the benfits of form like validation etc. can be replicated while doing the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax handlers are good but you still need to bind the form to an event to make it submit via ajax rather than on via a normal POST in the browser.

Try this:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('your logic here');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use [livequery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) for this. Livequery will attach ajaxForm to any form that is loaded in the DOM

```
$('form').livequery(function(){
$(this).ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function() {

        alert("Form submitted!");

        $('#results').html('Submitting...');
    },

    success: function(output) {
        var $out = $('#results');
        $out.html('Your results:');
        $out.append('<div>'+ output +'</div>');
    }
});

});
```